# Android - Not being able to retrieve file from external Share Button

Tags: android, file, share, android-external-storage

I'm trying to retrieve the file that the user wants to share via, for example, the Photo Gallery App. So, when they tap on the share button, and select my application, I'm retrieving the File's Uri through the method `Uri fileUri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);`. This works fine.

Then, I try to get the File whose Uri is the one I have. I do that this way:

`File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());`

But, afterwards, when I try to open it and read it, I get the `java.io.FileNotFoundException ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. Furthermore, when I execute the `file.exists()` method, it returns `false`. So I don't know where the problem is.

Here is the code:

```
Uri fileUri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());

FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I already have the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` tag in my manifest.

I must also add that the uri of the file which I retrieve is something like: "/0/1/content:/media/external/images/media/9412/ACTUAL/1989334571". As you can see, the file doesn't have any extension at all, so that might be the problem. Nevertheless, I don't know how to solve it.

EDIT 2:

It seems as it is a problem that started since KitKat...